# CMD no reconoce PHP wamp

Tags: cmd

Agregué la variable de entorno *wamp/php* y la `CMD` me sigue

> sin reconocer php como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutables

La ruta que agregué en `path` es la siguiente

```
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14\
```

windows 7 ultimate

Comment: Cerró y volvió a iniciar sesión?

Comment: Antes de la ruta de tu PHP no te hizo falta un ; ?

Comment: cerre sesion y no, supuestamente no se usa el ?